# How should I point to different repository mirrors in maven settings.xml

Tags: maven, maven-3

We have 2 separate products used by different teams and we would like to point to mirrorA for projectA and mirrorB for projectB. How can I achieve this in settings.xml and should I do this away from settings.xml and somehow reference in my project specific POM file.

```
  <mirrors>
        <mirror>
            <id>internal</id>
            <mirrorOf>*</mirrorOf>
            <name>Internal Release Repository</name>
            <url>http://192.168.1.4:7777/archiva/repository/internal</url>
        </mirror>
  </mirrors>
```

Note: This scenario happens when a developer contributes to both of these projects.

Comment: Why would you like to do this? Why not using the same repository, cause you have groupId, artifactId to distinct the products.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you might be confusing "mirrors" with "repositories". You should very probably not have a mirror configuration like that in your settings.xml. If different projects should deploy to or get their dependencies from different repositories, you just [specify those repositories](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#Repositories) in the respective projects' poms. Setting up mirrors solves an entirely different problem than setting up repositories does.